# Need a little advice with apc, node.js, varnish, memcached, nginx

Tags: nginx, memcached, varnish, node.js

Just need a little advice here if anyone can help. Currently i have nginx running on a virtual private server, i am looking into installing node.js so i can use AjaxIM (http://ajaxim.com/) , and installing memcached, apc, and varnish. The main page of the site will probably be updated around once an hour, and i plan on just using the default settings for each caching plugin, so I am wondering if all of these are going to work together. Also, does anyone have any experience with node.js querying a mysql database, and would i be saving myself some trouble by skipping some of these plugins and just using node.js for the sake of speed.

Comment: Badly written. Can you rephrase the question? It seems you have 2/3 questions bundled together.

Comment: hahaha yeah you are right, sorry give me one second.

Answer (score 1):

[APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_PHP_Cache#Alternative_PHP_Cache) is “[Alternative PHP Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_PHP_Cache#Alternative_PHP_Cache)”, so it’s not at all useful for Node.js applications.

Leaving out APC, then yes, all these work great together, but unless you have a lot of semi-static content, you are probably not going to benefit all that much from [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/), so you might leave that out for starters.

There is [a whole host of options for accessing MySQL from Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#database). I haven’t used any of them, but [db-mysql](https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/) looks promising. It's part of [Node.js DB](http://nodejsdb.org/) – you can find some examples there.

Comment: APC could be useful for Node.js in a way that it also acts as a data store that you can access. So if you have (a webserver with) PHP running with APC somewhere, you could fetch/store an object from APC with Node.js.